# Comparing two list boxes Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Listbox 1 contains names of hairdressers and Listbox 2 contains services provided by all of them then in Listbox 3 both the selected hairdresser(only 1 allowed) and and selected services are contained. There is a remove button which removes items from Listbox 3. I want a code for the button that if a hairdresser is removed all services also get removed otherwise only services are removed.

```
For Each str As String In Hairdresser.lstHairdresser.Items
 If Not lstHairdresserAndServices.Items.Contains(str) Then  
  lstHairdresserAndServices.Items.Clear()
 Else 
  'more code here but above statement never gets true 
 End If 
Next
```

Comment: Sure. What have you tried yourself so far? There are a few different ways to achieve what you're trying to do here, but before I'd suggest anything I'd like to see what kind of effort you've put into solving the problem yourself.

Comment: For Each str As String In Hairdresser.lstHairdresser.Items
            If Not lstHairdresserAndServices.Items.Contains(str) Then
                lstHairdresserAndServices.Items.Clear()
            Else
                'more code here but above statement never gets true
            End If
        Next

Comment: Add code to question not comments, you can format it there for easy viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hairdresser is always the first item in the 3rd listbox, all you have to do is check if the selectedindex equals 0. If so, clear the listbox. Otherwise just remove the selected item.

Alternatively, you could search the the 1st listbox for the selected string. If found clear the listbox otherwise remove the selected item.

It is also possible to mark the listbox items when you add then to the listbox. Set the tag property to something like "hairdresser" or "service" and when the remove button is clicked all you have to do is check the tag property.

Finally I would recommend a different approach: Instead of adding the items to the listbox, fill a data structure with the hairdresser's name and services, display this structure in the listbox and when the remove button is clicked compare the selected item to the structure to find out what was selected.